# One LAN internet One Wi-Fi router and One PC

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, desktop-computer

I have bought an ASUS DSL n10S modem. I want to share internet connection with Wi Fi devices and a desktop pc at home.

However, the problem is that the router that I bought has only one LAN port and RJ11 port. The internet signal is coming from a RJ45 LAN cable to which I connected to the router. How can I make desktop PC connect to the internet?

Will an RJ45 splitter help in sharing internet? Like, I connect the main LAN to the splitter and then use two other LAN cables on the other end of splitter, one going to pc and other LAN to the router.

I tried, but it is not working as I expected. Either router or the pc work at a time.

What options do I have to provide internet for desktop PC as well as the ASUS router?

Comment: No, a RJ45 splitter is not what you need.  Just get yourself a wireless access point, hook it up to the LAN port on the modem, then connect all your devices to the wireless access point.

Comment: @Ramhound, DSL n10S has wireless capability. There is no need to hook up additional access point to LAN port. OP also states that his Internet connection is coming in via RJ45/LAN, so the only LAN port is used.

Comment: @Suchit, does your desktop PC have a wireless NIC?

Comment: @smc - The author should clarify what their question is because I was confused.

Comment: The Internet coming into your home, is it purely a "modem" (i.e. the only output is a single RJ45 to connect "a" computer to?)

Comment: @smc no..i'm thinking about buying  a cheap usb wifi adapter...but i want to if there is other alternatives

Comment: @Suchit, I believe I have provided reasonable list of alternatives in my answer below. Tyson has helped with adding some detail to it.

Answer (score 2):

[ASUS DSL n10S](http://www.asus.com/in/Networking/DSLN10S/) is a wireless modem / router. It is designed mainly to create WiFi access point. You can, however, connect maximum of 1 PC on a wired LAN but the rest of devices have to be connected via WiFi.

[image]

To connect 1 PC via wired LAN, you need to have this single LAN port available and for this you would need to use ADSL socket for WAN connection. If your internet connection comes into the router via RJ45, then you can only connect wireless devices to your DSL n10S.

Splitter won't do the job for you.

You have following options:

1. If your are subscribed to the broadband via ADSL, then just connect your RJ11 and free your RJ45 to use it for PC
2. If your PC has a wireless NIC, then just connect to the router via WiFi. If this is not the case, you might consider buying a wireless NIC - they come with USB or PCI interface.
3. Get a different device as a replacement for your ASUS DSL n10S. You could swap your router for one that has more LAN ports. [DSL-G31](http://www.asus.com/uk/Networking/DSLG31/overview/) would be a reasonable replacement. (just as example, don't consider this as advertising). As you can see on the picture below, it has 4 LAN ports.

[image]

Comment: Good answer. One thing that should be explained tho, since the OP seems to have lots of wires to hook up and it is unclear what devices might also have a wireless interface.  To expand the wired LAN jack beyond one port, a "switch" (example for google: ASUS GX-D1081) can be used.  If the OP is going to have to buy more hardware to configure his network he should be aware of that option.  The wired "switch" is what is used when a "splitter" is needed.

Comment: @Tyson , thanks for comment. Its a valid point. I have updated my answer accordingly. However GX-D1081 is not the right choice for OP, since he has stated that he still wants to connect some Wireless devices along with his desktop PC.

Comment: that depends, while he could replace his DSL n10X as your edit, he could also keep the n10x and use a gx-d1081 like device to literally "split" the single port of the n10X.

Comment: @Tyson, true. That is an option.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed reply. I have a wimax internet connection. The internet comes via RJ45 cable from the outdoor unit. However, it also has RJ11 port from which I guess I can connect like you said in the first option. 
[wimaxinternet](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-dRfp7PCz4Xc/TxVpjif281I/AAAAAAAAD4s/YEjC78t45V4/s1600/WIamx.png)

Comment: Well, I recommend you to try it and let us know the result.

Comment: I purchased this ASUS DSL n10s router to replace Netgear DGN-1000 router which has disconnection problems.It works, but drops internet every few minutes. Internet is not much used in the desktop pc, only my parents use to occasionally check their email and I don't think little drops would concern them. Since I don't want to bring their attention into this internet problem, I'm looking for a cheap solution for this ( instead of buying  wifi adapter for pc).

Is it possible to pair the _faulty_ Netgear router as secondary router with ASUS, so I can connect pc to internet via Netgear?

Comment: I kind of tried it, but the RJ11 cable is not lengthy enough. I will have to place router outside house!

Comment: In that case the N10X is really the wrong piece of hardware for you.  You either need a non-dsl router, or possibly just a "switch". The determining factor is does the "wimax" "outdoor unit" provide just a single connection, or does it also provide router services such as DHCP.

Comment: @Tyson I see an option for DHCP in the wimax control panel [screenshot](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-rDVlWXvCs_M/VA3Cud-C2II/AAAAAAAAFn4/wI-ETJYeDVc/s1600/wima.jpg) 
If N10X is not right hardware, then which router/switch can I use?

Comment: Since this is not a product recommendation site, I'll stick to a generic answer.. You want one like the second picture above, except the yellow jack will be RJ-45 and labelled WAN.  Plug the RJ-45 from outside into that port. Your wired devices can plug into the 4 LAN ports.  You will want to change the default configuration of this new router to "Bridge Mode" since the WiMax device is providing DHCP services.  The end result is this allows to use wifi and gain 4 wired ports.